# How to convert a json data into a List<widgets> in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-futurebuilder

[a sample of what i have in mind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n8a9.png)

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=egg';

Future<BookResponse> getData() async {
  var response = await http.get(url);
  var responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
  // print(responseBody);

  return BookResponse.fromJson(responseBody);
}

-----

 FutureBuilder<BookResponse>(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                        title:
                            Text(snapshot.data.items[index].volumeInfo.title),
                      ));
                    });
              } else
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            },
          )
```

im trying to create a method that will convert json map into a `List<widgets>` so i can use it to display items.

i can't find a way to display items as rows and columns.

is it possible to have multiple widgets using `FutureBuilder`? (one row of **books** and another row to show **authors** for example)

if so i will avoid converting it to `List<widgets>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert JSON data to objects and:

```dart
Row(
  children: entities.map((entity) => Text(entity.text)).toList();
),
```

It creates a list with widgets.

Comment: i have mapped them with objects,

 im trying to display them as a row and not a list

Comment: Row(
                children: snapshot.data.items
                    .map((entity) => Text(entity.text))
                    .toList(),
              )

it's still not displaying. 
do i need to change the entity ?
if im calling items individually in a text(snapshot.data.items[0].title), it works just fine

Comment: It is not displaying or items incorrectly displaying?

Comment: Can you add screenshot?

Comment: i have put them in a row like so: `Row(
                children: [
                  for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.items.length; i++)
                    Text(snapshot.data.items[i].id)
                ],
              )`